# SVG path area overlap

Tags: svg, hover, overlap

I just started playing with SVG today and I can't figure out how to do hovering with non-rectangular shapes without having hover area overlap issues, as you can see in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49JSQ/2/).

If anyone could point out my missing knowledge I would really appreciate it.

```
<svg height="444" width="257" class="svg svg1">
  <path d="M0 148 L257 0 L257 297 L0 444 Z" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;"  
      onmouseover="document.getElementById('fade1').style.opacity = '.9';" 
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('fade1').style.opacity = '0';"/>
</svg>  
<svg height="444" width="257" class="svg svg2">
  <path d="M0 148 L257 0 L257 297 L0 444 Z" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;"  
      onmouseover="document.getElementById('fade2').style.opacity = '.9';" 
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('fade2').style.opacity = '0';"/>
</svg>  
<svg height="444" width="257" class="svg svg3">
  <path d="M0 148 L257 0 L257 297 L0 444 Z" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;"  
      onmouseover="document.getElementById('fade3').style.opacity = '.9';" 
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('fade3').style.opacity = '0';"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place all of the paths in the same SVG in order to have the hover effects work like you desire. This is due to the SVG elements (not the paths) overlapping each other, which with Z-indexes doesn't work like you want it to

With that being said, you can't position `<path>`s very easily, so I used [this tool](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg_transforms) to apply the styles you had. Alternatively you could put them in individual `<g>` elements and position them that way

The other thing to note is you should apply the `:hover` effects to the paths, not the SVG element

```
/* SVG */
<svg height="1150" width="257">
    <path d="M0 244L257 96L257 393L0 540z" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;"/>
    <path d="M0 545L257 397L257 694L0 841z" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;"/>
    <path d="M0 846L257 698L257 995L0 1142z" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;"/>
</svg>

/* CSS */
svg {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:257px;
}
svg path {
    opacity:.3;
}
svg path:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/49JSQ/4/)

P.S. I'm assuming the javascripg `onmouseover`s and `onmouseout`s are from a failed attempt?

Comment: Well I was using the onmouseovers and onmouseouts to change the opacity of images with the fade Ids when I hovered over the corresponding paths. I'll try out what you told me and tell you how it works out. Thanks alot.

Comment: @user3372093 If you find a question to be satisfactory to your question you can mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to the question, which will then give both the answer-er and the OP (original poster - you) reputation for doing so

Comment: Yey!! It worked. You can check out the result if you'd like. http://wolfsbrain.com/welcome.html

Comment: @user3372093 I like it! You might play around with delaying the transition so that the images can be seen a little bit more clearly, but it's just an idea

Comment: Or perhaps just fade it out instead of jumping

Comment: Yeah I forgot to  un-comment the transition easing. Looks better now.